# How to hide true image path (or revoke access to)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, url

I own a website where any user can upload photos of their daily lives. Let's, for the sake of simplicity, say all images are located in the following path:

```
www.example.com/assets/img/<USER_ID>/<PHOTO_ID>.png
```

The problem is, this allows anyone to view the photos of any person, which is not something I want. For example, here are some URLs anyone could go to and see the photos of any user (and even run a script to get all photos off the site):

```
www.example.com/assets/img/501/15631.png
www.example.com/assets/img/1375/78974.png
www.example.com/assets/img/2/52.png
```

How can I hide the true path of the image or prevent a user from viewing that image if they aren't following that person?

Comment: Don't even think about doing this in javascript, you need a server-side solution like [uLogin](http://ulogin.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: You have to provide those images through the server-side script, which will check the permissions.

Comment: Is it okay to use PHP, or do you have a particular language you need to use?

Comment: @EnzoMac PHP is perfectly fine.

Comment: Okay, I posted some code.  See if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two general approaches:

1. The simple one: When storing the images, add a “password-like” string to the file name (e.g. `15631_wCz3YiBZ5A2.png`), so that it becomes very unlikely that somebody can guess the name of an existing file.
2. The clean one: Have the static files served through a PHP file or something which checks if the current user is allowed to view the file. It is more work and puts much more load on the server, but it is more secure and more flexible. This could look like this:

```php
if (userMaySeeImage($imageId))
{
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    echo file_get_contents($imagePath);
    exit;
}
else
{
    die('Nice try, buddy.');
}
```

This is of course just a generic example, because I don't know anything about your user authentication/authorization mechanisms, and nothing about the way you store the image references.

In the example, `userMaySeeImage` is a function or method that can determine if the user may access the image, `$imageId` is the unique identifier for the image, and `$imagePath` is the absolute path to the image.

Comment: Do you have an example of the second method?

Comment: Yup, added a simple example.

Comment: Alright, but how would I call that PHP script and `userMaySeeImage` if a user goes to the direct image path? htaccess redirect?

Comment: The image wouldn't even be “publicly” available, i.e. stored outside the document root, or in a protected folder (htpasswd or chmod/chown so that public users mustn't access it).

Answer (score 0):

Do this, it masks the URL by reading the image and creating a new one.

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
$imgPath="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Sun920607.jpg/50px-Sun920607.jpg";
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgPath);
imagejpeg($image);
```

Comment: Why use `imagecreatefromjpeg` and `imagejpeg`, and not `file_get_contents`? Also, why should the image be loaded via the external URL and not via a file system path?

Comment: @lxg file_get_content can also be used but often not allowed by host providers due to security reasons. I used an external URL for no particular reason, I was making an example on the fly.

Comment: `file_get_contents` itself is not blocked, but the access to remote ressources sometimes is. Otherwise, you'd also have to block `require`, which would make running almost any PHP application impossible.

Answer (score 0):

It's an image. It can be copied, someone can do a screenshot, so you don't need more security than to make them undiscoverable. Once someone learns the url of a given image, while logged in, it doesn't matter whether he is logged in or not.

Therefore, this is an ok solution:

1. Use the hard-to-guess filenames as lxg suggests in the other anwer.
2. Configure the server to not allow the listing of files. On Apache and others compatible this can be done with a **`.htaccess`** file containing the following line:

**`Options -Indexes`**

Put that file in the directory you want to disable listings in. When client enters url to directory
`www.example.com/assets/img`
Instead of list of files and subdirectories he gets error **403 Forbidden**

Now it's impossible to view the file listing, and your files are named like this:
`3210983j11kjdhasda980132132.jpg` so it's impossible to guess their names.

Thats not tight security, but it's simple and it works well enough for very basic privacy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `.htaccess` protection, here is what I would do:

Create an .htaccess protected directory to house the user's pictures.  Then, when the user wants to follow someone, they would have to re-enter their password (many places do this for added security).  When they were to follow someone, you could use a form like this:

```
 <form name="signup" action="controller.php" method="POST" id="signup">
    <input name="user" placeholder="Username"></input><br>
    <input name="pass" placeholder="Password"></input><br>                              
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" style="border:none; background:MidnightBlue; color:white;" name="submit">
 </form>
```

Then, you need to take their password and place it into the .htpasswd file.  Here is that code (let's call this code file "controller.php"):

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];


$encrypted_password = crypt($password, base64_encode($password));

$data= $username . ':' . $encrypted_password . "\n";

$file = "user-directory/.htpasswd";       
$ret = file_put_contents($file, $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

?>
```

I have tested this and it works all right for me.  If you need anything, just let me know.